# put ubuntu on USB stick

Tags: live-usb

I believe I downloaded UBUNTU OS correctly, and tried to load it onto a usb stick, but I am unable to boot-up from the stick. any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Which OS are you currently using ,the one you downloaded Ubuntu ISO in

Answer (score 1):

If you have windows installed on your machine, i would recommend you using Rufus. its a very famous tool to create bootable USB drive
Download it from the page:
https://rufus.akeo.ie/. this tool is the answer to create bootable media for any kind of OS. if you face any issue using the tool, comment back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an in-built software from ubuntu to put that on USB Stick.
Go to System Tools -> Administration -> Startup Disk Creator. Select the USB device and the Ubuntu image. Would take about 2minutes and then you are done.

Comment: To be clear, this answer only applies if you're currently running Ubuntu on your computer. These instructions will not work if you're running Windows or OS X.